# How to stop jsqmessagesviewcontroller indicator spins when video download finished

Tags: swift, swift3, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

There is a way to stop the jsqmessagesviewcontroller activity indicator spins when video download finished?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

when you want to stop and hide indicator write this code

```
activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
activityIndicator.alpha = 0
```

and when you want to start and show indicator write this code

```
activityIndicator.startAnimating()
activityIndicator.alpha = 1
```

Comment: Are you serious?

Comment: You do not know what time to download it ends?

Comment: If you find a solution please post it as an answer, it can help other, thanks